# What is difference between 10/5 and 10%5 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

What is difference between 10/5 and 10%5 in JavaScript? Are both same ?

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/operators

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Does Modulus Divison Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10/5 is division operation and depending on the data type storing the result in might not give you the result expected.  if storing in a int you will loose the remainder.

10%2 is a modulus operation. it will return the remainder from the division and is commonly used to determine if a number is odd or even.  take any given number mod 2 (N%2) and if the result is is 0 then you know the number is even.

Answer (score 5):

```
10/5 = 2
10%5 = 0
```

`%` is modulo

Answer (score 3):

One is your basic division operation:

```
10/5 => 2
10/4 => 2.5
```

The other is the modulo operator, which will give you the integer remainder of the division operation.

```
10%5 => 0
10%4 => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

10/5 divides 10/5 = 2
10%5 divides 5 and returns the remainder, 0, so 
10%5 = 0

Comment: What is mean of rerun to remainder

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

10 / 5 is 2.
10 % 5 is 0.

Answer (score 0):

% is the modulus operator: it gives you the remainder of the division.

Answer (score 0):

10 / 5 is 10 divided by 5, or [basic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)).

10 % 5 is 10 modulo 5, or [the remainder of a division operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 0):

In pretty much every language % is a modulus not a divide symbol. It does divide but it gives you just the remainder rather than the divided number.