# if statement: how to code "if a is a multiple of b"

Tags: loops, if-statement

I would like to write "if i is a multiple of 11" then

System.out.print("|")

But I'm not sure how to do this?

I'm trying to incorporate sides on the edge of my 'tank of fish'.

The situation might be silly but I think the question is valid.

```
--------------------------------------------------
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#><
----------------------------------------------------

public class partCC
{

    public partCC()
    { 
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    {
    for (int i=0; i<43; i++)



     {if (i > 0 && i%10 == 0)  
        System.out.println(); 

        System.out.print(" <#><");

    }
    {if 
       (i

      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("----------------------------------------------------");
    }


    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It think you should look at [How Does Modulus Divison Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work) just to understand why this answer is right.

the answer in your case is `if ((i % 11) == 0) { System.out.print("|") }`

Answer (score 2):

`if ((a % b) == 0) System.out.print("|");`

The modulus operator % returns the remainder after dividing a by b which will always be 0 if a is divisible by b.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the `Zero` in condition

```
if(i != 0 && (i % 11) == 0) System.out.print("|");
```

because initializing `i` with zero would produce `|` at first loop cycle too as `0 % 11` would produce `0`