# python big number mod

Tags: python, numbers, modulus

I'm doing mod for big number in `python 2.7.3` and python is giving me wrong answer as shown below. If number is small, then it gives correct answer.

Can anybody explain why this happens and how I can fix in python??
below simple script showing small number mod shows correct answer but big number mod gives wrong answer.

```
root# cat mod.py 

bigNum=46623871433466988486147975697094761425185742805822717249007
smallNum=717249007

print "bigNum % 3: " + str(bigNum % 3)

print "smallNum % 3: " + str(smallNum % 3)

root# python mod.py

bigNum % 3: 0  
smallNum % 3: 1
```

Appreciate for help in advance.

Comment: Where is the wrong answer? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work.

Comment: I'm getting the correct answer 0 too... what's the expected result and why? :)

Comment: guys,
shame on me.
this is first time posting question and I was too quick to think python is giving me wrong answer. Indeed python is giving me correct answer. 
Sorry guys and thanks for correcting me quickly.

I'll be more prudent next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you expect it to return?  It looks right to me:

```
>>> bigNum=46623871433466988486147975697094761425185742805822717249007
>>> bigNum % 3
0L
>>> divmod(bigNum, 3)
(15541290477822329495382658565698253808395247601940905749669L, 0L)
>>> _[0] * 3 == bigNum
True
```

Note that the sum of digits is divisible by 3, so `bigNum` is also:

```
>>> sum(map(int, str(bigNum)))
288
>>> 288 % 3
0
```

Comment: Both you and DSM mentioning the sum of digits trick and pretty much the exact same approach... :)

Comment: That surprised me too - but I beat him by 15 seconds because I didn't bother to sum the digits of 288 too - LOL ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this is first timer mistake and I'll be more prudent next time. Shame on me. I've accepted this as an answer.