# objective-C algorithm obstacle

Tags: objective-c

This piece of code is inside shake event's scope,

```
if(i % 3) {
    self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y];
    y += 1;        
}
```

whenever i reaches 3,
y += 1 executes.

When I shake it again,

y value adds another 1
i is now equal to 4

So now i = 4 and y = 2, I get the idea why y is adding another 1 but I just can't figure out how to avoid it, please help.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: What does i represent?

Comment: You should try to learn basic programming, the most basic about the what operators are doing will help you already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Does Modulus Divison Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)

Comment: I am really sorry @alinoz for being new and just trying to ask question and learn.

Comment: @frustratediOS developer before asking questions you should invest a minimum effort for understanding what are you doing. no body can just put the knowledge directly in your head. There are some steps that can not be bypassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
if(i % 3  == 0){

        self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y];
        y += 1;        
}
```

This code will increase y only every 3rd iteration (or shake or whatever you are doing)

Comment: That did it! thank you so much! I changed the 0 to 1 though :)

Comment: @frustratediOSdeveloper That will cause the code to execute when `i-1` is divisible by 3. It will still occur only once every three times, but there will be a shift in when the execution occurs. (Which may be desired behavior if `i` starts at 0 before any shakes, increases by 1 for each shake, and you want `y+=1` to start with the first shake rather than the third, I suppose.)

Answer (score 6):

Try `if (i % 3 == 0)`. By using `i % 3`, the piece of code will execute *whenever `i` is not divisible by 3* rather than *only* when `i` is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way can you try this:

```
if(i % 3 == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Value of i : %d and Y is : %@", i, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y]);
    self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y];
    y += 1;        
} else {
    NSLog(@"Value of i : %d and Y is : %@", i, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y]);
}
```