# Purpose of using modulus to find a numbers?

Tags: c#, modulus

Really been racking my brain trying to understand Modulus.

This is an exercise question and the guidelines for it.
here is my exercise question:

> Write an expression that looks for a given integer if its third digit
>   (right to left) is 7.

The guidelines say this:

> Divide the number by 100 and save it in a new variable, which then
>   divide by 10 and take the remainder. The remainder of the division by
>   10 is the third digit of the original number. Check if it is equal to
>   7.

So I followed the guidelines and wrote the code. Here is my code.

```
Console.WriteLine("Input 3 digit Number");
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
input /= 100;
input %= 10;
if (input == 7)
{
Console.WriteLine("number is 7!");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("number is not 7");
}
```

Problem is I don't understand how it's working, lets say I input 712 as a number, it's 3rd digit to the left is 7, so it should work, and it does the console will tell me it's 7.

However if I was to calculate 712 / 100 that's 7.12. The to calculate a modulus I take the input (now 7.12) divide by 10, subtract the whole number (this is decimal so I subtract 0.71 and multiply by 10 again, so I'm left with 0.02.

If I run 7.12 % 10 into C# however I get 7.12 as the output. How?

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy really need help on this.
Why is modulus being used and how is it getting the output it's getting?

P.S. I do understand Integers don't take decimals so it would output as 7 not 7.12 (hence the code says its 7) So I understand that bit.

Comment: call to string on the number, if it has >=3 chars in its char array check if the character is 7 - unless the homework dictates you must use mod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`712 / 100` IS NOT `7.12`. It's `7`. If you'll divide `7` by `10`, then you'll get `0`. If you'll take modulus of `7 % 10`, you'll get `7`, because it's the rest of dividing `7/10`. Dividing ints always rounds down to the full decimal value, there is no rest. That's what the modulus operator is for and you need to evaluate them separately.

Example:

Your input is `12345`. `12345/100` gives you `123`, because you have `123 full hundrets` in the input. Then `123/10` would give you `12`, because there are `12 full tens` in `123` and `123%10` would give you `3` (which is the number you're looking for), because it's the rest from dividing `123/10`.

And if you'll ever need division in the school-math type, use floating point types, like `float` or `double`. F.e. `12345f/100` would give you approximately `123.45f`.

Comment: C# doesn't have a modulus operator, it has a *remainder* operator.  [What's the difference?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)

Comment: Another educational day on Stackoverflow. Thank you :)

Comment: @Tarec I knew I missed something obvious and stupid, thank you, I knew integers don't have decimal values and I missed that. Modulus makes a little more sense now as well :)

Comment: @Servy I had no idea there was a difference, I'll read that web page now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here actually has nothing to do with `C# %` operator.

It is because you are using `int` vs. `double`

- `int` will always be an integer, so it rounds down as others have stated.
- `double` for example will keep decimal places.
- The `C# %` operator doesn't care and doesn't round down - it just gets you the remainder in the same type used for the input

***Here's a quick test:***

```
int inputAsInt = 712;
inputAsInt /= 100;
inputAsInt %= 10;

Console.WriteLine(inputAsInt);
// prints 7

double inputAsDouble = 712;
inputAsDouble /= 100;
inputAsDouble %= 10;

Console.WriteLine(inputAsDouble);
// prints 7.12
```

Comment: C# doesn't have a modulus operator, it has a *remainder* operator.  [What's the difference?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)

Comment: Ok I took the word mod out of there. I thought % was always referred to as the mod operator. Either way the gist of my answer explains what the OP is seeing and asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo is a very different operation to divide.

Another way you can think of it is the remainder of an integer division.

[See this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664304/726986)

```
27 / 16 = 1, remainder 11
=> 27 mod 16 = 11
```

[Wiki Page on Modulo Operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: division always results in a rational number too, assuming the dividend and the divisor are rational.  (and of course, none of the numeric types on C# are *capable* of representing an irrational number.)

Comment: No, it creates a *rational* number.  It sounds like you don't know what the definition of a rational number is.  An number that can be represented as the division of one integer by another is a rational number.  An irrational number is one that *cannot* be represented in that form.  On top of that, in C# `10/3` is actually an *integer* number.  It's `3`.  It's not even a rational non-integer number.

Answer (score 0):

N / 100 "removes" digit one and two from the number and then (N / 100) % 10 removes all digits after the third digit:

```
N = ABCDE

N / 100 = ABC 

ABC % 10 = C
```