# C# Operator Modulus?

Tags: c#, console, sum, modulus

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WholeNumbers1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            int Threedigitnumber;


            Console.WriteLine("Enter in three whole numbers");
            Threedigitnumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            sum = sum + (Threedigitnumber % 10);    // Add third digit to sum
            sum = sum + (Threedigitnumber / 10) % 10; // Add seconed digit to sum
            sum = sum + (Threedigitnumber / 100); // Add first digit to sum

            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", Threedigitnumber, sum);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how and why this code works to calculate the sum of three numbers? Im confused on how exactly the % works and why division is needed here? How does this work?

Comment: Modulus returns 'one side', (integer) division the 'other side'. Write down the values after each individual operation to see what is occurring.

Comment: what do you mean "side?"

Comment: Write down the values after each individual operation to see what is occurring. What is `t % 10`? What is `t / 10`? What is `(t / 10) % 10`? What is `t / 100`?

Comment: how do you calculate %

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427602/c-sharp-modulus-operator (keep in mind it varies between languages; but this is C#, and used on a positive integer typed value). also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759390/purpose-of-using-modulus-to-find-a-numbers-c-sharp?rq=1 and https://www.linqpad.net/ is a nice tool to play with

Comment: thanks a ton . I think i get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you introduce 123.

```
Step 1: 123 % 10 = 3; 
        Sum = 3
Step 2: 123 / 10 = 12;
        12 % 10 = 2;
        Sum = 5
Step 3: 123 / 100 = 1;
        Sum = 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is calculating the sum of digits.

when you input lets say is 123

1) sum = sum + (Threedigitnumber % 10);

`(Threedigitnumber % 10);` returns  remainder i.e when you divide 123/10 the remainder is 3 .so your sum at this point is `3`

2) sum = sum + (Threedigitnumber / 10) % 10;

`(Threedigitnumber / 10)` returns the quotient i.e when you divide 123/10
the quotient is 12 and when you call mod (%) again it returns remainder as 2 (12%10=2) and then add it to the sum which now become 3+2=5;

3) sum = sum + (Threedigitnumber / 100);

`(Threedigitnumber / 100)` returns the quotient i.e when you divide 123 by 100 it outputs 1. After adding 1 to your sum your sum now becomes 3+2+1=6

This is a terrible way to calculate the sum of the digits.An more efficient way would be

```
        int num, sum = 0, r;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (num != 0)
        {
            r = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : "+sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Modulus means remainder after a division.  In this case it is used to isolate the digits in the one's place and the ten's place.  Anything `mod 10` will give you the digit in the one's place.  It's the remainder after dividing by 10.  So `175 / 10 = 17`, while `175 % 10 = 5`.  To get the tens place, they divide by 10 first, which division drops the one's place altogether (since this is integer arithmetic).