# What does a percentage sign (%) do mathematically in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I am super confused what the percentage sign does in Objective C. Can someone explain to me in language that an average idiot like myself can understand?! Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

% is the modulo operator, so for example 10 % 3 would result in 1.

If you have some numbers `a` and `b`, `a % b` gives you just the remainder of `a` divided by `b`.

So in the example `10 % 3`, 10 divided by 3 is 3 with remainder 1, so the answer is 1.

If there is no remainder to `a` divided by `b`, the answer is zero, so for example, `4 % 2 = 0`.

[Here's a relevant SO question about modular arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work).

Comment: It should be noted that this is only true of positive values. Things like (-1)%3 will return `-1`, not `2`

Comment: Hey, is the modulo function actually related to arithmetic, as in mathematics or unique to c / objective c / c++ ??

Comment: Related to arithmetic. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 4):

[Same as what it does in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), it's "modulo" (also known as integer remainder).

Comment: So why is the result of 3%10 is 3? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: @AeroWindwalker: 10 goes into 3 0 times, with a remainder of 3.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the modulo operator. It returns the remainder of `<number> / <number>`. For example:

```
5 % 2
```

means `5 / 2`, which equals 2 with a remainder of 1, so, `1` is the value that is returned. Here's some more examples:

```
3 % 3 == 0 //remainder of 3/3 is 0
6 % 3 == 0 //remainder of 6/3 is 0
5 % 3 == 2 //remainder of 5/3 is 2
15 % 4 == 3 //remainder of 15/4 is 3
99 % 30 == 9 //remainder of 99/30 is 9
```

The definition of modulo is:

> **mod·u·lo**
>
> (in number theory) with respect to or using a modulus of a specified number. Two numbers are congruent modulo a given number if they give the same remainder when divided by that number.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematics, The Percentage Sign %, Called Modulo (Or Sometimes The Remainder Operator) Is A Operator Which Will Find The Remainder Of Two Numbers x And y. Mathematically Speaking, If x/y = {(z, r) : y * z + r = x}, Where All x, y, and z Are All Integers, Then
x % y = {r: ∃z: x/y = (z, r)}. So, For Example, 10 % 3 = 1.

**Some Theorems And Properties About Modulo**

- If x < y, Then x % y = x
- x % 1 = 0
- x % x = 0
- If n < x, Then (x + n) % x = n
- x Is Even If And Only If x % 2 = 0
- x Is Odd If And Only If x % 2 = 1
- And Much More!

Now, One Might Ask: How Do We Find x % y? Well, Here's A Fairly Simple Way:

1. **Do Long Division.** I Could Explain How To Do It, But Instead, Here's A Link To A Page Which Explains Long Division: https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/long-division-index.html
2. **Stop At Fractions.** Once We Reach The Part Where We Would Normally Write The Answer As A Fraction, We Should Stop. So, For Example, 101/2 Would Be 50.5, But, As We Said, We Would Stop At The Fractions, So Our Answer Ends Up Being 50.
3. **Output What's Left As The Answer.** Here's An Example: 103/3. First, Do Long Division. 103 - 90 = 13. 13 - 12 = 1. Now, As We Said, We Stop At The Fractions. So Instead Of Continuing The Process And Getting The Answer 34.3333333..., We Get 34. And Finally, We Output The Remainder, In This Case, 1.

**NOTE: Some Mathematicians Write x mod y Instead Of x % y, But Most Programming Languages Only Understand %.**