# What does the % symbol mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, modulo

What does the % symbol mean in Ruby? For example, I use the following code:

```
puts "Roosters #{100 - 25 * 3 % 4}"
```

And get the following output:

```
97
```

Where the deuce did the 97 come from? I've looked up what the modulo operator is and still have no idea what it does in this simple mathematics example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work

Comment: What do you know think of the result of `75 % 4`?

Comment: [Fixnum#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-25) is just another garden-variety method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo operator.

It does division and returns the remainder. So, in your case, 75 / 4 is 18 with a remainder of 3.

25 * 3 = 75

75 % 4 = 3 (the remainder)

100 - 3 = 97

Answer (score 1):

modulo - divide with remainder

divide, and take the remainder from the integer division.

```
10 / 3 = 3 (with remainder 1 that we discard with integer division)
10 % 3 = 1 (the part we normally discard is the part we are interested in with mod)
```

It is also used to create cycles. If we had a sequence of 1 to N, we could mod it by M and produce a cycle. Assume M = 3 again

```
for n in 0..10
   m = n % 3
   puts "#{n} mod 3 = #{m}"
end

0 mod 3 = 0
1 mod 3 = 1
2 mod 3 = 2
3 mod 3 = 0
4 mod 3 = 1
5 mod 3 = 2
6 mod 3 = 0
7 mod 3 = 1
8 mod 3 = 2
9 mod 3 = 0
10 mod 3 = 1
```