# How to add the even numbers up in multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list

For example, the lists are `[1,2,3]`,`[4,5,6]`, and `[7,8,9]`. I want to add only the even numbers up in all the lists, so that would be 2+4+6+8=20. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How would you go about adding up *all* the numbers in the lists?

Comment: have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like this for example:

```
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
sum(val for v in l for val in v if val % 2 ==0)
```

Comment: These one-liners...gotta love Python

Comment: with `itertools.ifilterfalse` and `itertools.chain`: `>>> sum(ifilterfalse(lambda x: x%2, chain(*[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])))
20
`

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through each list, and sum up the even values.

```
theSum = 0
lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for list in lists:
    for item in list:
        if item % 2 == 0:   
            theSum += item
```

The (%) sign used in this context is known as modulus, it will return the number of remainders when a number is divided by another. So far example here, any number that can be divided by 2 without any remainders is an even number e.g. 8 % 2 returns 0.

```
       if item % 2 == 0:   
            theSum += item
```

As you can see by the if statement, we go through all the items and test if they can be divided by 2 without leaving remainders. If they can be, we add them together.

[Here is more information about modulus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
sum = 0
for x in a+b+c:
  if x%2 == 0:
    sum += x
```

Comment: don't use sum  as a variable name

Comment: Ah, right.  Reserved keyword.  Thanks!  I'll leave the original, but you're right!

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, but here is a good start for you.

You can merge all the lists together into one list:

```
lst =[1,2,3] + [4,5,6] + [7,8,9]
```

Then you can make a list of just the evens:

```
new_list = [n for n in lst if is_even(n)]
```

**Note**: you must write is_even

```
def is_even(n):
    # return True if even
    # otherwise return False
```

Then you can iterate through the list and add up all the numbers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[7,8,9]
sum(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,a+b+c))
```