# How 30%4 output is 2 but if I write 30*4/100 output is 1

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("30%4 = " + 30%4);
System.out.println("33%4 = " + 33%4);

System.out.println("30*4/100 = " + 30*4/100);
System.out.println("33*4/100 = " + 33*4/100);
```

My Question is why 2 not 1 in 30%4 case. Can anybody explain me in details. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Those are basic modulo and division arithmetics, I would google it instead.

Comment: `30%4=2` since remainder `2`. `30*4/100 => 120/100=1`.

Comment: `4*7=28` so `30-28 =2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The % operator is modulo, it takes the remainder after division of the two numbers, in your case it divides 30 by 4, the highest multiple is 7 as 7*4 = 28 now the remainder is 2, which is your answer, for the 33 case it does the same, 8*4 = 32 remainder is 1

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand how modulus works. =) when you apply modulus it gets divided and returns the "remainder"...

[How Does Modulus Divison Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)
there is a very good explanation already posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
30 % 4 = 2
```

because:

`4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4` is `28` so `30 -28 = 2`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, integer division returns the floor of the computation (rounds down to the nearest integer). This is why 30*4/100 comes out to 1.

On the other hand, modulus (%) is the remainder of integer division. Since 28 is divisible by 4, the remainder of 30/4 would be 2 (as 28+2=30).