# What does the modulus do?

Tags: c++, math, modulo

I never really get it, but what does the modulus operator (`%`) do.

And when would you want to use it in a mathematical context? By the way, I

just want to know what it does, not how it works.

Comment: Did you miss how to do manual division in elementary school somehow?

Comment: No, I didn't. Did you?

Comment: Is it me in question? It's you who was asking for something trivial.

Comment: Never mind what I said.

Comment: Plus, it's not even trivial if you're a beginner.

Comment: It's all well [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/modulus).  No need to ask here.

Comment: That's way too complicated for me, thank you very much.

Comment: The mod operator basically means "remainder after division".  For example, `11 % 3 == 2` (because `11 == 3*3 + 2`).  Another example: `25 % 7 == 4` (because `25 == 7*3 + 4`). HTH

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no need to be an a-hole

Comment: thanks superbatfish and Albert Renshaw!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Does Modulus Divison Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)

Comment: Not really.That isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calculates the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) of a division operation.

```
5 / 2 == 2   // whole part of the division
5 % 2 == 1   // remainder
```

In other words you could reconstruct the original number by

```
2 * 2 + 1 == 5
|   |   ^ remainder
|   ^ whole part
^ divisor
```

Comment: Wow, thanks alot. I kind of get it now!

Comment: But how exactly do you use it?

Comment: What do you mean how do you use it? It is an arithmetic operator, you use it the same way you would use `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc. For example `int remain = 5 % 2;`

Comment: @SamuelL. for example if you wanted to check if a number was even you could say does `x%2==0` or "if I divide by 2 is there NO (0) remainder.

Comment: Thanks for the help!