# How to call a method when a value reaches multiples of 5

Tags: java, android, if-statement, multiplication

I have Firebase database where a number value is stored for a specific user. I want to show an advert when the value reaches multiples of 5, starting at 0.

I can get it to call the method from for the first multiple of 5 using an if statement like this

```
  if (ads < 5 && dls > 5) {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Testing it worked here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How can I edit this so it calls it at 10, 15, 20, 25 and so on?

Comment: Take a look at the modulo `%` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the modulus operation.

```
if (dls % 5 == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(c,"Testing it worked here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664304/7788355) explains more about the modulus operation if interested :)

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo operation as shown below

```
if (value % 5 == 0)
```

Read more about modulo operation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)