# How does % sign work in javascript

Tags: javascript

How does `%` sign work in javascript. Following code gives output `0/1`.

```js
for(var i= 0; i<10;i++){
   console.log(isOdd(i))
}
function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;}
```

Comment: Nothing special, classical modulus

Comment: [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work

Answer (score 0):

```
a%b
```

Its the modulo operator. It trys to put the biggest multiple of b into a, then returns the rest of it:

```
2%3 /*3 fits 0 times, remainder is */ 2
6%5 /* 5 fits once, remainder is */ 1
16%5 /* 5 fits three times, remainder is */ 1
```

Its really useful for *endless* arrays, so if you go over the max index, start again at 0, which can be written like this:

```
i++;
if(i>=array.length) i=0;
```

Can be shortened to:

```
i=(i+1)%array.length;
```