# Log file showing up empty

Tags: powershell

I have  script that outputs a log file, now I need to read this log file and create  a new log file for when it finds the words WARNING & ERROR and i need it to write the line number and output an error code from 0-20 for ERROR and 21-40 for WARNING, but everytime I rn the script my ExitCodeLog.lg is empty.

```
$file =  'H:\REPO\ADNEW\Testlog.log'#@(Get-ChildItem -Filter Remove-StallUserObjects_*.log)[-1]
$lineNumber = 0
$errorCode = 0
$warningCode = 21
$output = ForEach ($line in $file) {
    $lineNumber++
    if ($errorCode -eq 20) {
        $errorCode = 0
    }
    if ($warningCode -eq 40) {
        $warningCode = 21
    }
    if ($line -cmatch " ERROR: ") {
        "$lineNumber $errorCode"
        $errorCode++

    }
    if ($line -cmatch " WARNING: ") {
        "$lineNumber $warningCode"
        $warningCode++

    }
}
$output | Out-File -FilePath 'H:\REPO\ADNEW\ExitCodeLog.log'
```

Comment: Did you try to print only the value of `$line` with `Out-Host`? Why should the loop iterate a file name? 'H:\REPO\...' is a string not a file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is, that the contents of `$file` is a plain string.

You should use

```
$file = get-content 'H:\REPO\ADNEW\Testlog.log'
```

Furthermore you can optimize the first two if statements by using a modulo operator:

```
$errorcode = $errorcode % 20
$warningcode = 21 + ($warningcode % 20)
```

Comment: Thank you, silly me i forgot get-content, now it works, also i dont want to use the modulo operator as im new to this and i don't know exactly what its doing.

Comment: No problem. Modulo is the remainder of a division. So 10 % 3 = 1 because 10/3 = 3  remaining 1. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work) for an explanation... ;-)