# What does "bucket entries" mean in the context of a hashtable?

Tags: hashtable

What does "bucket entries" mean in the context of a hashtable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a hash table work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work)

Comment: Don't believe them -- "bucket entries" are what hashtables do before they're deallocated.

Answer (score 48):

A bucket is simply a fast-access location (like an array index) that is the the result of the hash function.

The idea with hashing is to turn a complex input value into a different value which can be used to rapidly extract or store data.

Consider the following hash function for mapping people's names into street addresses.

First take the initials from the first and last name and turn them both into numeric values (`0` through `25`, from `A` through `Z`). Multiply the first by 26 and add the second, and this gives you a value from `0` to `675` (`26 * 26` distinct values, or bucket IDs). This bucket ID is then to be used to store or retrieve the information.

---

Now you can have a *perfect* hash (where each allowable input value maps to a *distinct* bucket ID) so that a simple array will suffice for the buckets. In that case, you can just maintain an array of 676 street addresses and use the bucket ID to find the one you want:

```
+-------------------+
| George Washington | -> hash(GW)
+-------------------+      |
                           +-> GwBucket[George's address]
+-------------------+
|  Abraham Lincoln  | -> hash(AL)
+-------------------+      |
                           +-> AlBucket[Abe's address]
```

However, this means that George Wendt and Allan Langer are going to cause problems in the future.

---

Or you can have an *imperfect* hash (such as one where John Smith and Jane Seymour would end up with the same bucket ID).

In that case, you need a more complex backing data structure than a simple array, to maintain a *collection* of addresses. This could be as simple as a linked list, or as complex as yet *another* hash:

```
+------------+       +--------------+
| John Smith |       | Jane Seymour |
+------------+       +--------------+
      |                     |
      V                     V
   hash(JS)              hash(JS)
      |                     |
      +-----> JsBucket <----+
                 \/
+-----------------------------------+
| John Smith   ->  [John's address] |
| Jane Seymour ->  [Jane's address] |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Then, as well as the initial hash lookup, an extra level of searching needs to be carried out within the bucket itself, to find the specific information.

Answer (score 17):

From **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)**:

> hash table or hash map is a data structure that uses a hash function to map identifying values, known as keys (e.g., a person's name), to their associated values (e.g., their telephone number). Thus, a hash table implements an associative array. The hash function is used to transform the key into the index (the hash) of **an array element (the slot or bucket) where the corresponding value is to be sought.**

[image]

Each entry in the array/vector is called as an Bucket.

Answer (score 6):

I think **Bucket** is a structure that at least contain hash value, which works as indexes, (hash values are generated by hash functions), but the structure itself might contain entries (data) or not.

illustration:

[hash value][points to actual data]  ---> [actual data]
|<------------bucket structure------>|

[hash value][actual data]
|-----bucket structure--->|

It is the [hash value] part works as indexes.

---

I found these photos from [hash_table Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hash_table#/Separate_chaining) are pretty straightforward.

The photos below indicates that entries (data) can be stored within buckets or it can be stored with its own data structure, while bucket simply points to the data.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both rehashing and coalesced hashing assume fixed table sizes determined in advance. If the number of records grow beyond the number of table positions, it is impossible to insert them without allocating a larger table and recomputing hash.

Another method of resolving hash clashes is **separate chaining**. Term **Bucket** is generally used with separate chaining. Separate chaining involves keeping a distinct linked list for all records whose keys hash into a particular value.

Suppose that hash function produces values between 0 and tablesize - 1. Then an **array bucket** of header nodes of size tablesize is declared. This array is called the **hash table**.

**Bucket[i]**, bucket entry, points to the list of all records who keys hash into i. To insert a record, the list head bucket[i] is accessed and record is inserted at the tail end.