# Why can index of backing table in java.util.HashMap be the same for two different provided keys?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashcode

Internally HashMap has method *hash()* which defends against poorly written hash-code by applying special function. 
Next step is that returned value by *hash()* method is used to calculate index at which new Entry is stored inside backing array called *table*.
It can happen that *index* is the same for two different keys. For that linked list is used but it is clear to me.

**Why can index of backing table be the same for two different keys?**

I know that hash-code can be poorly overriden but method *hash()* states that it protects from hash-code collisions. So why can index of backing table be the same?

**EDIT** Thanks to all for replies. @Dunkan Jones resize is done automatically when amount of elements you put into HashMap (*size*) is more or equal to threshhold(calculated according to initialCapacity and loadFactor provided in constructor). Look into method createEntry - *size* is incremented whenever new Entry is created. 
My question is why does hash() method + indexFor() method return together the same index for different objects. Due to this same index two Entries are put at the same bucket by means of linked list.

**What causes hash() + indexFor() methods return the same index?**

I think and can't realise what hash() and indexFor() do by those tricky >>> and & operators?

What hashing in HashMap means ?

Thanks again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work

Comment: Check this (http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html)

Comment: Because that's what hashing means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, every object that can be a key for a hash map should override `hashCode()` method, so the general contract (from Javadoc) is

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

In other words:

> `o1.equals(o2)` then `o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()`

Hash maps internally use another `hash()` function that create another hash code from `hashCode()` values. This function at some point use modulus (for space efficiency), so different `hashCode()` values can have equals `hash()` value (keys are mapped with `hash()` value).

This is not a problem, because if two keys in the map have equals `hash()` value, will be compared with `equals()` method when searched, to ensure they have the same key, and no two objects which, by coincidence, have the same hash code.

Some resource:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

### Edit after the OP edit

I think `indexFor` calculates the modulus. The function is

```
static int  indexFor(int h, int length) {
   return h & (length-1);
}
```

We know (from [theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) that `a % b == a & (b - 1)` iff *b* is 2<sup>*n*</sup>. The length field (our "*b*") is multiple of 2<sup>*n*</sup>:

> Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which defends against poor quality hash functions. This is critical because HashMap uses **power-of-two length** hash tables, that otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.

So different hash value can have same modulus, hence different object can have same index.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the internal `hash()` method is used to improve the quality of the results of `hashCode()`. The internal Javadocs describe why:

> Retrieve object hash code and applies a supplemental hash function to the
>    result hash, which defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is
>   critical because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
>    otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
>    in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.

However, your underlying question appears to be: **Why does the hash map allow multiple values to sit in the same "bucket" rather than just extending the size of the map?**

The answer will be performance. It is expensive to recompute all the hashes in the map during a resize operation. Up to a certain point, it will be cheaper to stuff multiple values into the same bucket.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Not, hash() method is used to defend against poorly written hash-code because it takes hash-code and applies special function! Next, value returned by hash() is used to determine index of backing table by method indexFor(). indexFor() uses bitwise & operator applying length of backing table thus returns index within table bounds. Question is why can that index returned by indexFor() be the same.

Comment: Thanks,but why indexFor() can generate the same indexes for different results of hash(). But maybe hash() generates the same results from different hash-codes. I know that HashMap grows automatically when there is no enough buckets so there is always enough space and somehow HashMap puts two Entries at the same bucket

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi I've edited my answer to hopefully address your actual question.