# How are buckets organized in the Hashtable

Tags: c#, hash, hashtable, hashcode

MSDN says:

> When an element is added to the Hashtable, the element is placed into a **bucket** based on the hash code of the key.

But I cannot find any information how are buckets organized or created. How are buckets ordered(alphabetically)? What basic principle to create a bucket in a hashtable?

I mean for example, a word "Tom" has a hashcode which is 3. Well, a word "TomTom" has another hashcode, for example, which is 6. My question is in which buckets will these words be putted and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a hash table work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work)

Comment: @TomTom have you read this article? There is a some supposition of buckets. However, it is just a supposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you not find that basic information? Even Wikipedia has a good explanation? I mean, seriously. This is basic data structures 102 - there are tons of books about it. There are sites about it. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) describes ton of methods to do that. How the .NET framework does it is not important (implementation detail) as it may change between versions, and even then - the source code is public, so "no information" is wrong again.

For example [here you can find](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,10fefb6e0ae510dd) the official source code for .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: yeah, I've read this articles but I cannot understand what a bucket is. Is this a spot for one item or we can put many items in the bucket?

Comment: So now we are back to you now knowing basic data structures and enough programming to understnd them. Voting to close as now it beecomes clear this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work ;)

Comment: this topic is about how are buckets created not how does hashtable work:).

Comment: That is in the code. Look, the explanations in wikipedia, the reference an the code are all you need. If you have a problem with thise, a beginner C# or a fundamental programming book are more appropirate - or maybe the understanding that you just aren ot cut as a programmer because if this is making your problems, things get a LOT worse later.

Comment: I mean for example, a word "Tom" has a hashcode which is 3. Well, a word "TomTom" has another hashcode, for example, which is 6. My question is in which buckets will these words be putted and why?