# Hash Table in Raw Flash or simple file system for embedded system

Tags: database, embedded, filesystems, hashtable, cortex-m

I am developing a handheld data logger. The CPU is a STM32F10x, the storage chip is a 16MByte SPI-Flash.

Information of the Flash Chip:
Sector Size: 4096 Bytes
Programming Page Size: 256 Bytes

Currently I am using a simple File system. I append the acquired record to a binary file. The data is not necessarily stored as a file.

The structure of the record:

```
typedef struct strRecord{
    char Info[56];
    uint32_t TimeStamp;
    uint32_t SomeNumber;
....//Some other data
}Record;
```

The length of the record is fixed. Before the record is appended to the simple binary file, the system must query if there is a record has the same Info(the first member of the structure) already exists in the file. If such a record exists, the new record will be merged to that record, otherwise a new record will be appended. There are no relation between these records, they come in random.

Currently I use an exhaustive approach, read from begin to end and compare. This solution only works when the file contains just hundreds of record or less.

The problem is : As the file size increases, the query process will become very  slow. The system should work with tens of thousands of record.

I have attempted to port an older sqlite version to the system, but I have only about 140K of Flash size and 48K of RAM to spare. I could only trim the database to about 200K and the attempt failed.

Since the record has a fixed-length string in it, maybe some Hash-Table style trivial structure would rescue me. But all the string hash-table algorithm implementations I know of store the hash-table in memory.

Could anyone give me some hint of how to implement a hash-table on simple File System or Raw Flash.

Comment: Guess this link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work?rq=1

Comment: This link discusses hash table in general but I still have no clues for my problem. My problem is : I have limited Flash and RAM space. I don't need and couldn't afford a full-fledged database like SQLite. I want to implement a hash table using string as key but would like to store the information of the hash table in raw flash or simple file system. I must admit I lack a deep understanding of the hash-table. I will read the link to see whether I could get some inspiration.

Comment: We are no consulting or tutoring site. Your question is off-topic here, see [ask].