# What's the difference between the return of hashCode() and a key in a hashTable?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I have to code a perfect Hashing table for a homework, but I'm struggling to understand:

What's the difference between the return of hashCode() and a key in a hashTable since I have to implement the methode getKey() but I only know that the index of an object x is given by ((a * x.hashCode() + b) mod p) mod m when a and b are random integers, p a prime number and m the size of the table.

Since the index is given by H(key), that means that x.hashCode() is the key in my opinion, but I'm not sure because the key and the value (only integers) are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a hash table work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work)

Comment: Two keys can have the same hash code without being equal.

Comment: The key is the object of the key type. The hash code is not the key, it's a number associated with the key.

Answer (score 1):

`hashcode()` method produces the expected result of applying the object's hashing method on a specific instance, whereas the key is the object itself.

Bear in mind the object can be another complex/composite object ( say another HashMap). As long as it has a reasonable implementation of `hashcode()` and `equals()` , it'll work just fine.

If two instances produce the same `hashcode()` result and  `equals()` compares according to that result ( setting aside type checks, but they're of-course, also part of the test), the objects are deemed equal/identical.

This gets really interesting once you start working with TreeMaps ( where equality is not based on hashcode/equality, but rather on  ordering, `Comparable`s and `Comparator`s)

Comment: This is why it's important that `equals`, `hashCode`, and `compareTo` (if used) must be consistent. Ideally so will `toString`.