# What does this mean? Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];

Tags: java, hashmap

I am studying how `HashMap` works inside and can not understand this method:

> ```
> void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
>         Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
>         table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
>         if (size++ >= threshold)
>             resize(2 * table.length);
> ```

Why object **`e`** gets the address (or what happens here?) of `table[bucketIndex]` and then this `table[bucketIndex]` get the new `Entry(hash, key, value, e)`? What is the reason, why didn't just use what is below?

```
Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value)
table[bucketIndex] = e;
```

Comment: What version of JDK is this?

Comment: Forgetting things specific to Java for a moment, do you understand the abstract data structure known as a "hashtable" or "hashmap"? If not, you may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730620/17300) and some of its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there could be collisions in the `HashMap` (i.e. different keys which produces the same `bucketIndex`). If they did what you suggests, in the case of a collision, the last inserted element would delete the previous ones in the case of a collision, possibly in a virtually unpredictable manner.

The `Entry` is implemented as some sort of linked list, so it is actually a bit misnamed and is in fact a node of linked list of entries. This is the reason why `e` is passed as the last parameter of `Entry` constructor.

Creating a new `Entry` that refers to the previous one (the `e`) and adding it in the same place where the `e` was is the operation of inserting a new node in the beggining of the linked list, and works even if `e` was `null` (i.e. there was no collision at all and the created `Entry` is the first one with the given `bucketIndex`).