# How does Python's bisect function use this tuple as an argument?

Tags: python, hashtable, dna-sequence, bisect

This is a question arising from a Coursera course on genomics that I'm following. We are currently dealing with search methods, specifically how to detect (align) all occurrences of a shorter DNA sequence (**p**, a string) within a longer DNA sequence (**t**, also a string). The approach in question involves the creation of a **hash table** for **t** composed of all possible substrings of length **k** AND their positions (each substring is a so-called **kmer**). We then search the hash table with substrings of the same length (kmers) derived from **p**. This involves the creation of an **Index** class and the eventual use of Python's **bisect_left** function. Here's the code:

```py
import bisect
import sys

class Index(object):

    def __init__(self, t, k):
        ''' Create index from all substrings of size 'length' '''
        self.k = k  # k-mer length (k)
        self.index = []
        for i in range(len(t) - k + 1):  # for each k-mer
            self.index.append((t[i:i+k], i))  # append (k-mer, offset) pair (tuple)
        self.index.sort()  # alphabetize by k-mer
    
    def query(self, p):
        ''' Return index hits for first k-mer of P '''
        kmer = p[:self.k]  # query with first k-mer
        i = bisect.bisect_left(self.index, (kmer, -1))  # binary search
        hits = []
        while i < len(self.index):  # collect matching index entries
            if self.index[i][0] != kmer:
                break
            hits.append(self.index[i][1])
            i += 1
        return hits
```

My question concerns the format of the **bisect_left function**. Python docs gives the syntax for this function as follows:
**bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a), *, key=None)**
The bisect_left function used in my course is formatted in this way:
**i = bisect.bisect_left(self.index, (kmer, -1))**
I understand that the parameter **a** has been passed the argument **self.index**, which is the hash table created from **t**. But then I'm flummoxed by the **tuple** which follows. I don't see how any of the following parameters accepts a tuple. I can imagine that the hash table is organized as tuples of the form (kmer, position), but none of these entries will have the position **-1**. The instructor states that he sets the value to -1 for a specific purpose as follows:

"So the first step is to just find the first k basis of p to look them up in the tables. So, I'm going to say kmer equals p up to length k, and we need to do self.k. And now I want to **find the first position in the list where this kmer occurs**, so I'm going to use **bisect** to do that quickly. And say i = bisect.bisect_left. And I pass in the list that we're searching for, and then the object that we're searching for. And remember this is a list of **tuples** so I'm going to pass in the **kmer**, and then I'm going to put **-1**. And **since all the indices in the list are greater than negative one, this assures that we always get the first occurrence** of that."

I mean, I understand the English, but I don't see how bisect can (a) take in a tuple as an argument, and (b) assuming it can (obviously it can), how can it make use of a position, -**1**, that doesn't exist in the hash table? I have a hunch I'm not cluing in to what's going on in terms of sorting, but I can't put my finger on it.

Many thanks, and sorry for what must be the overly long statement of my question.

Comment: Why would it not be able to take a tuple?

Comment: What 'hash table' are you talking about? A list of tuples is not a hash table, if that's what you mean

Comment: There's nothing special about a tuple here; the elements of the list being bisected are themselves tuples, so a tuple is the one thing that can be meaningfully compared to them.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone, especially @decorator-factory! Yes, I see now, as more than one person has noted, that I am not dealing with a hash table, but rather a sorted list. (The immediately preceding lecture was on hash tables and for some reason I assumed that we were using hash tables in the next lecture.) I also understand now how the tuple is read for sorting. Thanks again! (And apologies if I'm not supposed to use the comments box for thanking. I vaguely recall that that might be verboten.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, you can compare tuples lexicographically (like in a dictionary). First, the first elements are compared, then the second elements, and so on.

```
>>> (1, 2, 3) < (1, 2, 4)
True
>>> (1, 3, 3) < (1, 2, 4)
False
>>> ('a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e') > ('a', 'r', 't')
False
>>>
```

`bisect.bisect_left` is not restricted to integers or strings, and it works with any objects that can be compared. In fact, you can see how it's implemented here: [GitHub link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/bisect.py#L68-L99)

As the [documentation on bisect_left says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left), it searches for the index at which to insert the new tuple so that the list is still sorted.

For instance, this list is sorted:

```
[("a", 1), ("b", -42), ("c", 2), ("c", 3)]
```

And this is not:

```
[("a", 1), ("c", 3),  ("b", -42), ("c", 3)]
```

---

Example of using `bisect.bisect_left` with tuples:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left

# The shopping list must be ordered by food type first, by
# quantity second.
shopping_list = [("apples", 100), ("bananas", 42), ("grapes", 250)]

# Say, we want to figure out where to put our cherries.
print(bisect_left(shopping_list, ("cherries", 666)))  # 2
# Our new list might look like this:
[("apples", 100), ("bananas", 42), ("cherries", 666), ("grapes", 250)]
# (just for illustration, bisect_left doesn't change the list)

# What if we want to find out where the bananas start?
print(bisect_left(shopping_list, ("bananas",)))  # 1
```

---

Thanks to Kelly Bundy's comment: `(kmer,)` is a better value to use than `(kmer, -1)`. `("foo",)` is indeed less than `("foo", whatever)`. This is better if your requirements change and now `-1` is a valid second element.

---

P.S. The `self.index` list is not a hash table. It's simply a sorted list of tuples. It doesn't have any special searching capabilities (besides allowing binary search, which is what you're doing). There is [a great talk by Brandon Rhodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66P5FMkWoVU) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work) for an explanation of hash tables.