# Hash buckets in the context of std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

I'm trying to understand hashing in the context of `std::unordered_set`. [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) gives this explanation:

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
> organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
> entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to
> individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the
> exact bucket the element is placed into.

My problem is that I cannot understand what it looks like in memory. Perhaps this question should address hash tables in general, but this may have too much dependence on implementation as all the explanations of hash tables I managed to find were abstract.

As far as I can guess, *buckets* are dynamically allocated contiguous pieces of memory, something like arrays, but they are not necessarily contiguous relative to each other, whereas *hashes* are something like pointers to these arrays stored contiguously.

Am I correct on this?

Comment: Have you tried to implement a hash-table yourself? I highly recommend you find a tutorial and try it. That should give you a very good insight how it works and what "it looks like in memory". As one of the basic data-structures it should really be part of any decent computer science course.

Comment: It can be a vector. It can be a dynamically allocated array. It can even be a binary tree map. There are trade-offs for each kind. I don't know if the standard specifies something specific or the standard library devs are free to do what they please.

Comment: Check this diagram - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Hash_table_3_1_1_0_1_0_0_SP.svg And [read the following manual about hash table with buckets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: I  tried to explain how hash tables work more visually in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567466/410767).

Comment: "buckets are dynamically allocated contiguous pieces of memory, something like arrays, but they are not necessarily contiguous relative to each other, whereas hashes are something like pointers to these arrays stored contiguously.  Am I correct" - no.  Over simplifying a little, think of the separate chaining implementations of hash tables - like `std::unordered_set` and ...`map` - as `std::vector<std::list<T>> buckets_;`.  You have a contiguous array of "buckets".  "Hashes" are not pointers - they're numbers that are %-ed into the bucket count to create bucket-array indices.

Comment: The exact layout in memory also depends on the allocator

Answer (score 0):

The standard implementations of `std::unordered_set` / `std::unordered_map` use a separate-chaining hash table.

This means that the hash collisions are solved chaining together the collided elements through a linked list, which can be traversed in order to access the element with a unique search key. The internal organization of memory depends on several factors, including the implementation choices of the individual library, but it is essentially a dynamic-size array of pointers, which always point to the first element of its linked list, if present.

This is a common and simple method, but that often leads to a rapid performance degradation, especially with high overloads (load factors >0.8) and requires more memory usage to store the information necessary to keep track of the nodes.

An in-depth article can be found [here](https://bannalia.blogspot.com/2013/10/implementation-of-c-unordered.html?m=1).